# How to display lightning checkboxGroup in 2 column without disturbing other slds form elements?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, checkbox

What CSS would be required to make the items in a lightning:checkboxGroup display horizontally in two or three columns?

i have tried this Css

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__control {
display: grid !important;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr !important;}
```

it displays checkboxGroup horizontally and the breaks it in two columns but it's affecting other lightning:input fields layout as well.

Comment: its kind of hard to tell without seeing the HTML and a visual of the layout, current effect and desired one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code resolved my issue.

Cmp:

```
 <div class=" multiSelect">
            <lightning:checkboxGroup aura:id="selectReason"
                                     required="true"
                                     label="Select Reason/s"
                                     options="{!v.options}"
                                     value="{!v.value}"
                                     onchange="{!c.handleReasonChange}"/>
            </div>
```

Css:

```
    .THIS .multiSelect .slds-form-element__control
{
    display: grid !important;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr !important;
}
```